# shift cell value form one time stamp to other in R

Tags: r, time-series

Is it possible to shift data of one cell in a column from one timestamp to other in a time series data without losing any other data? I have tried shift and slide functions but it replaces the data with NA values. 
I have tried using mutate function as well but it changes the complete column.Is There any function or method to perform manipulation?

E.g, convert :

```
Date_Time  | x | y    
01-01-2016 | 1 | 2    
02-01-2016 | 3 | 4
03-01-2016 | 5 | 6 
04-01-2016 | 2 | 5
```

to:

```
Date_Time  | x | y
01-01-2016 | 5 | 2
02-01-2016 | 3 | 4
03-01-2016 | 1 | 6
04-01-2016 | 2 | 5
```

or slide the data vertically

```
Date_Time  | x | y
01-01-2016 | 2 | 2
02-01-2016 | 1 | 4
03-01-2016 | 3 | 6
04-01-2016 | 5 | 5
```

Comment: I don't understand the rules you're trying to impose. How are you deciding which values you're moving, and where they're going? Also it would help to see the code that didn't work.

Comment: I am trying to swap the cell of timestamp with maximum value with the timestamp having the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

Two swap two values you need to hold one in a temporary variable. We can write a simple function:

```
swap = function(x, i, j) {
  stopifnot(length(i) == length(j))
  temp = x[i]
  x[i] = x[j]
  x[j] = temp
  return(x)
}
```

On your data, it should work like this to give the desired result:

```
your_data$x = swap(your_data$x, which.min(your_data$x), which.max(your_data$x))
```

Comment: I am getting following error while implementing the swap function in a loop.

    Error in which.min(allData[i]) :  
     (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
     Called from: swap(allData[i], which.min(alldata[i]),          which.max(allData[i]))

Comment: Don't know what's going on without seeing your loop code. Are you looping over row or columns? The swapping is vectorized in the swaps, so looping over rows shouldn't be necessary. If you're looping over columns, use `allData[[i]]` or `allData[, i]` to use a vector, `allData[i]` is still a list/data frame, just with only one column.

Answer (score 0):

Two other options with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = case_when(
    x == max(x) ~ min(x),
    x == min(x) ~ max(x),
    TRUE ~ x
  ))

df %>% 
  mutate(x = replace(x, c(which.max(x), which.min(x)), c(min(x), max(x))))
```

**Result:**

```
    Date_Time x y
1 01-01-2016  5 2
2 02-01-2016  3 4
3 03-01-2016  1 6
4 04-01-2016  2 5
```

To shift `x` vertically:

```
df %>%
  mutate(x = c(x[-1], x[1]))
```

or

```
df %>%
  mutate(x = c(x[length(x)], x[-length(x)]))
```

**Result:**

```
> df %>%
+   mutate(x = c(x[-1], x[1]))
    Date_Time x y
1 01-01-2016  3 2
2 02-01-2016  5 4
3 03-01-2016  2 6
4 04-01-2016  1 5

> df %>%
+   mutate(x = c(x[length(x)], x[-length(x)]))
    Date_Time x y
1 01-01-2016  2 2
2 02-01-2016  1 4
3 03-01-2016  3 6
4 04-01-2016  5 5
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "Date_Time  | x | y    
01-01-2016 | 1 | 2    
02-01-2016 | 3 | 4
03-01-2016 | 5 | 6 
04-01-2016 | 2 | 5", header = TRUE, sep = "|")
```

Comment: I am trying to apply 'for' loop to perform mutate function with the case.  
but I am not getting the desired result, actually, there is no change. Do I have to do do something different for the loop to work?

Comment: @neekitanarayan Your question is not clear, what are you applying the for loop to? and what is your desired result? My solution matches your desired output, so if you have any additional specifications, please edit your question body to incorporate the new information.